# Date Language doesn't change

Tags: date

i've switched to Italian Language for my wordpress website and it shows the translation correctly, but when i try retrieve date and time with this code `echo "<span class='date' style='margin-left:-20px;'>"; echo date('l, jS F, Y'); echo "</span>";` it gives me an output in English. Why is happening this ?

Comment: try this function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n

Comment: @mmm as an answer (with a little bit more context) please :)

Comment: @Rarst no I'm feed up by users who downvote my answers without explainations then I will no more write answers if a comment is enough to help.

Comment: @mmm the problem is such questions haunt site as "unanswered" and it is much harder to spot helpful information in a tiny comment, than a proper answer. You are always welcome to inquire on meta for advice on how to improve your answers, if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

The `date()` is a native PHP function. Its output depends on PHP locale and timezone settings. In a typical WP environment that would be default English locale and UTC time zone (which WP sets during core boot).

Since WP implementation of Date/Time component predates PHP 5 and its enhancements, it has a lot of own functions and conventions.

The appropriate WP function to use for localized output of date is `date_i18n()`. It depends on *WP* locale and time zone settings, ignoring PHP ones.

It should be noted that there are *many* outstanding edge cases and breakage with `date_i18n()` implementation. Any use of it must be carefully audited for correctness, especially for output of timezone information.